# Upgrading Python 3 on Windows broke all my downloaded modules

Tags: python-3.x, upgrade

I'm using Windows 7 and am up to date on patches.  I was using Python 3.5.2 and wanted to upgrade to 3.6, so I went to the Python site, downloaded 3.6.4.exe for Windows, and ran it.  The Python seems to work fine and is 3.6.4, but trying to import any of the packages I was using (pandas, numpy, tensorflow, etc) now gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <whichever module it was>`.  Also, `pip list` now shows only pip and setuptools.

It appears to be a known issue, for example [this](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/883) from nearly a year ago, which suggests that I should "uninstall the python bindings and install again", but I can't figure out what that means.  Fortunately I can still access 3.5.2 by using `py -3.5`, and then my imports work.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this for 3.6 without having to reinstall all my modules manually?

I was thinking possibly I should have upgraded through pip; it seems like that's possible but maybe a bad idea for some reason?  On further investigation it looks like what I should have done was save my requirements with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, and then after installing the new Python restore them with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  Is this right?

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? These sorts of dependency problems are what they are made for. As a general rule, keep your python(s) as clean as possible on your machine and install all pypy packages in a virtual environment for you application. I can't be certain, but you may need to do nothing with your machine except set up a virtual environment and re-install your packages. Search "virtualenv", "virtualenvwrapper", and "add2virtualenv".

Comment: I didn't think I needed virtualenv, since I just wanted to replace 3.5 with 3.6, rather than maintaining both of them.  I'm looking into it, but can you tell me how I would have used virtualenv in this situation?  I realize that I can probably fix things by manually reinstalling all my packages, but that's something I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say if you have an install problem, but this is what I would try if I were in your place.

1. Create a virtual environment as per; [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

   c:>c:\Python36\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv
2. Activate your virtual environment

   C:> \Scripts\activate.bat
3. Run your application from within your activated environment. Each time you get an import error, do a pip-install from within the active environment. (For your own modules, you may need to modify PYTHONPATH in 'activate.bat')
4. Once you have your application running again, do your pip freeze > requirements.txt, and keep that with your project.
5. Each time you run your application, do so from within the activated virtual environment.

This will give you a clean requirements.txt that doesn't include a bunch of junk from other projects. Then, when you go to 3.7, just create the virtualenv and run your requirements.txt and wala!

I suspect your issue is simply not running against the correct interpreter, running from within a virtual environment should at least rule it out.